# View PPT files directly in an iframe (with Chrome Office Viewer?)

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I am currently working on a local web-based application.  Here are the facts:

- I am using the CSS page transitions found here:
  http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/  Due to this, each "page" of my application is contained in it's own div in a single file.

Example:

```
<div class="pt-page pt-page-1">
<!-- Page 1 content goes here ... -->
</div>
<div class="pt-page pt-page-2">
<!-- Page 2 content goes here ... -->
</div>
```

...etc

- The client wants to be able to view Powerpoint (.ppt) files directly on the web browser.  To attempt a quick and dirty solution, I have installed the Chrome extension "Chrome Office Viewer" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-office-viewer-beta/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en to each machine(this application is going to be isolated to just four machines that will be using Chrome for the application, so usability isn't an issue here)
- **What I WANT to have happen** is to link to the .ppt file in an iFrame in one of my `<div>` pages as seen above, so when the user clicks on a link to view the PowerPoint, the page transitions and the slides can be viewed within the iFrame due to the Chrome Extension capabilitiy.
- **What CURRENTLY happens** is that as soon as the application loads, the page redirects to the browser FROM the original application page to a seperate page to view the .ppt file.  I would like this to be done inside of the `<iframe>` as mentioned earlier instead of an entire page redirect...

Is this possible or am I limited due to the construction of the Chrome Extension itself?  I can always have the client save their .ppt as images and then display those within a `<div>` page, but I figured the Chrome Extension would be the quickest solution.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Providing an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** or at least posting some relevant code, always helps get better/quicker responds...

Comment: @mithilatw What you're requesting ("I want to know a way to display office documents inside an element (iFrame or object) using Chrome Office Viewer extension.") is actually possible, though it requires some modifications in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Drive web publishing and embed your documents by iframes.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37579

Answer (score 0):

Try making a .html or .php (depending if you use php) and link the .ppt in it, and then just put that .html in an iFrame.

```
<div class="pt-page pt-page-1">
<iframe src="/page 1 file linked here"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="pt-page pt-page-2">
<iframe src="/page 2 file linked here"></iframe>
</div>
```

If it still redirects then its an extension thing.

Also in future try keeping away on reliance to extensions and browsers, they are not really reliable enough for commercial use.

And whats the intention of this system? If its gonna stay in the office for work why does it need fancy transitions?

EDIT:
If you need those .ppt files to be dynamic you can use PHP for dynamic .html creation.

Comment: The system is going to be a kiosk-type system that people can interact with locally.  I ended up just converting all the PowerPoint files to .wmv videos and displaying those instead :-)

Comment: Ok, please put the answer in here so the question can be closed

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/web/solutions/powerpoint-embed.aspx

This might help, unfortunately I couldn't find any other way, using iframe forces the browser to download the file, and embedding also doesn't work here. Moreover, this method also allows you to add controls below, and its almost same as an iframe window. :)